# regex - word boundaries

Tags: regex, lexer

I have two regexes to identify two different kinds of word. These are:

1. for identifier: [_a-zA-Z][_0-9A-Za-z]*
2. for number: (\d*\.\d+)(([eE][-+]?\d+))|\d+

I would like to know why the word 12aaa is seen as 2 words that is a number(12) followed by an identifier(aaa).

My purpose is that the word 12aaa be seen as a wrong identifier. How could i do that ?

Comment: Some example inputs and expected outputs would help with answering this question.

Comment: What about negative numbers?

Comment: You should have a \ in front of the `.` in your number regex. Otherwise it will match 4a4

Comment: @KjetilS. Thx for ur remark about negative numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `\b` (match word boundary) at either end of your regexes. That will force them to match within word boundaries only. So `12aaa` will no longer match as either a number or an identifier.

Also, as I mentioned in my comment, you should have a \ in front of the . in your number regex. Otherwise it will match 4a4.